# data.table compare groups using t.test

Tags: r, data.table, t-test

I have the following data structure.

```
dat <- as.data.table(cbind(var1=rep(1:5, 200), 
var2=rep(c("gp1", "gp2"), each=500), 
as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5000, 0, 1),ncol=5))))
```

What I'd like to do is to perform a t.test between gp1 and gp2 grouped by var1.  I have read through some other posts when there is only one column of data using something like:

```
dat[, .(p.value = t.test(V1 ~ var2, .SD)$p.val), by=.(var1)]
```

What I can't figure out for the life of me is how I can do this over all of the other columns (i.e. V2 to V5).  The vignettes have been helpful in pointing out the use of lapply(.SD, somefunction) to iterate over the columns but in this case I am not quite sure how to make that work for me.

The example above is a toy example, I am actually working with millions of rows of data and multiple hundreds of columns, so speed is a concern.  I am currently using a nested apply to iterate through the rows and columns and the function takes hours to run.  I am hoping for something speedier.

It would be even better if I can do this between 2 different data.tables.  (i.e. gp1 in its own data.table and gp2 in another).

Long time user of R, noob when it comes to data.table.

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: By using `cbind`, you are converting the columns to `character`.  Instead it should be `data.table(var1=rep(1:5, 200), var2=rep(c("gp1", "gp2"), each=500), ..`

Comment: @ken, I am just giving a try based on my _beginneR knowledge_ You can try split the data based on var1 `split <- split(dat, dat$var1, drop=FALSE)` and apply t tests, `pval<-lapply(1:length(spl), function (x) lapply(dat[,c(3:7)], function(x) t.test(x ~ dat$var2, var.equal = TRUE)$p.val))`. It'll give the p value as a list again which can be extracted using a loop further.

Comment: @akrun Can you please elaborate what difference does it make in terms of carrying out t test?

Comment: Thanks Enigma, I do have a solution that uses a nested apply like you suggested and it takes hours to run.  I was hoping to use some of the speed enhancement features in data.table to speed it up.  Thanks though!

Comment: @akrun,  this was a toy example for illustration.  My actual data has them as factors.  In any case, I am trying to compare gp1 and gp2 for each groups 1:5.  Perhaps a better example I would have used a to e.

Comment: Main thing is that I can't figure out how to use .SD twice, one to iterate through the columns and one to split between the 2 groups for each column to perform the t.test